# Entity Framework 6.1 Code First migration error: EntityType 'IdentityUserRole' has no key defined

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I created a new MVC 5 project and I tried to enable migrations for the Code First entities I've been creating, when I got the following PS exceptions in the Package Manager Console:

```
One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:

Project.Web.Models.IdentityUserRole: : EntityType 'IdentityUserRole' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
Project.Web.Models.IdentityUserLogin: : EntityType 'IdentityUserLogin' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
IdentityUserRoles: EntityType: EntitySet 'IdentityUserRoles' is based on type 'IdentityUserRole' that has no keys defined.
IdentityUserLogins: EntityType: EntitySet 'IdentityUserLogins' is based on type 'IdentityUserLogin' that has no keys defined.
```

The problem is that there are no classes called `IdentityUserRole` or `IdentityUserLogin` in my project.  There are classes with those names located in the `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework` namespace, but the error is saying that those classes exist in my project's namespace.

How do I resolve this issue?  I've cleaned and recompiled the project several times, and nothing seems to fix this issue.

## EDIT

If I remove my `OnModelCreating` override, everything works... This is what I have in the override:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<CommercialEntity>().ToTable("Commercial", "Entity");
    modelBuilder.Entity<ResidentialEntity>().ToTable("Residential", "Entity");
    modelBuilder.Entity<ContactsList>().ToTable("ContactsList", "List");
    modelBuilder.Entity<ListFacet>().ToTable("ListFacet", "List");
}
```

I want to set the Schema for my tables in EF.  Is there another way to achieve this that works with migrations?

Comment: This looks like it's an error coming from ASP.NET Identity 2, not necessarily Entity Framework. Have you tried removing the EF / Identity 2 nuget package?

Comment: I have removed all of the packages and re-added them, but the error still persists... Do you think I should tag this as an ASP.NET Identity issue instead of an EF issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just found the answer!   Playing around with the `OnModelCreating` override in my Db Context class, I realized I wasn't calling the base method.  I added the following line at the end of the override and everything started working!

```
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
```

Hope this helps someone else!